# Interleaving the rows of two different SQL tables, sorting by date

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgres I've got two different tables that have almost nothing in common, save for the fact that they both have a creation date. I'd like to use that creation date in order to display instances of both of those models on a timeline. To do that, I imagine I need to first somehow select all of the created_at timestamps from BOTH of the tables in one statement, then sort them in descending order, paginate the resulting set, and then go through and detect which model each of the rows corresponds to in order to properly display the data.

Any idea if this is possible?

Comment: You need to provide the table structures, some sample data and the expected output. To me it sounds as if you simply want a full outer join: `select coalesce(a.creation_date, b.creation_date) from table_a a full outer join table_b b on a.creation_date = b.creation_date order by 1`

Comment: An alternative approach would be a `UNION ALL` with a common column for the timestamp, and all the other columns replaced with NULL literals for the other table. So if each table had three cols, you'd have `SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.thetime AS thetime, a.aa AS aa, a.ab AS ab, a.ac AS ac, NULL AS bx, NULL AS by, NULL AS bz FROM a UNION ALL SELECT b.thetimecol, NULL, NULL, NULL, b.x, b.y, b.z) combined ORDER BY combined.thetime`. It's essentially a crude home-brew `FULL OUTER JOIN`; however, unlike a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, this will not combine rows where the timestamps are equal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe smth like this

```
select created_at, 'a' as tab_name from table_a 
union all
select created_at, 'b' as tab_name from table_b
order by created_at
```

Comment: This will only work if `table_a` and `table_b` have compatible columns, which doesn't sound like it's the case here.

Comment: Why? It's clearly stated that both tables have a creation date.

Comment: Er, I'm  blind. I thought you had a `table_a.*` and `table_b.*` in there. Somehow.

Comment: This is genius, and is exactly what I was looking for. A thousand thanks!